# How can I remove my profile picture from Chrome's navigation area (AKA the "You" button)?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, user-profiles

In Chrome 69, Google added a new UI that shows your avatar ("Gmail profile picture") in the top section of the browser even if you haven't signed into Chrome.

I liked the old UI better, and I hate having my profile picture there all the time.

How can I remove my profile picture from Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

## Old answer:

You can do this by reverting to the old Chrome UI. Go to `chrome://flags/#top-chrome-md` and change the dropdown setting to "Normal", then restart the browser.

[image]

Source: [This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/9gz8p4/how_do_i_undo_the_new_chrome_that_just_auto/), which has some other useful tweaks as well.

## New answer:

Google has removed the above flag, so that method no longer works.